# Get the data from jQuery when() into then()

Tags: jquery

I've been having trouble understanding how `when(`) passes data around. In this example, I need to use the id from `when()` in the `then()` statement. However, it fails to resolve. I've heard some things about `when()` returning a deferred, but I can't seem to understand how to use it.

```
// retrieve the id of selected point from the database, and remove the 
// point
var deletePointByLocation = function (lat, lng) {
    $.when(function () {
        var filters = [
            {
                'name': 'lat',
                'op': 'eq',
                'val': lat
            },
            {
                'name': 'lng',
                'op': 'eq',
                'val': lng
            }
        ];

        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            url: 'api/datapoints',
            data: {"q": JSON.stringify({"filters": filters})},
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'GET'
        })
    }).then(function (data) {
        var idx
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            url: 'api/datapoints/' + idx,
            type: 'DELETE'
        })
    }).done(function () {
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        _.forEach(mapCircles, function (circle) {
            if (circle.getCenter().equals(point)) {
                circle.setMap(null);
                var idx = mapCircles.indexOf(circle);
                mapCircles.splice(idx, 1);
                num--;
            }
        });
        toggleInfoDisplays();
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`idx` appear `undefined` at `url: 'api/datapoints/' + idx` ?

The `$.ajax()` calls are not being `return` ed within `$.when()` or `.done()` ?

`mapCircles` not appear defined at `.done()` ?

Try

```
var deletePointByLocation = function (lat, lng) {
    // add `return` before `$.when()` 
    return $.when(function () {
        var filters = [
            {
                'name': 'lat',
                'op': 'eq',
                'val': lat
            },
            {
                'name': 'lng',
                'op': 'eq',
                'val': lng
            }
        ];

       return $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            url: 'api/datapoints',
            data: {"q": JSON.stringify({"filters": filters})},
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'GET'
        })
    }).then(function (data) {
        var idx; // what is `idx` ?
        // add `return` before `$.ajax()`
        return $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            url: 'api/datapoints/' + idx, // what is `idx` ?
            type: 'DELETE'
        })
    }).done(function () {
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        // what is `mapCircles` ?
        _.forEach(mapCircles, function (circle) {
            if (circle.getCenter().equals(point)) {
                circle.setMap(null);
                var idx = mapCircles.indexOf(circle);
                mapCircles.splice(idx, 1);
                num--;
            }
        });
        // what is `toggleInfoDisplays` ?
        toggleInfoDisplays();
    })
};
```

Comment: Im calling some global variables and other functions in that part, that's what you're seeing. I wanted to get the id from from when() and put it in the idx variable

Comment: @Praetore _"wanted to get the id from from when() and put it in the idx variable"_ `data` variable at `.then()` should contain response from `$.ajax()` , could set `idx` by retrieving `id` from `$.ajax()` response